# Get pixel count according to a shapefile's identity

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have a raster that has 5 classes and a polygon shapefile with 10 rows.

This is the raster:
[image]

This is the shapefile with various shapes
[image]

I want to get the pixel count

1. by classes - 5
2. by identity (there are 10 in the shapefile).

Comment: As long as the polygons are not overlapping then the [Tabulate Area](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/tabulate-area.htm) tool should do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Tabulate Area will work for this. Shown below, is the result when I used the ROI feature class as the feature zone data, OBJECTID as the zone field, and Raster as the input raster. The result is a table that identifies the area per raster value per ROI area.

To determine the number of cells, you would need to divide the values in the Tabulate Area table by the area of the cells within your raster. For example, dividing 47.57 by 5.95 (the area of my raster cells) is 8, which is the number of raster cells with the value of 2 in the ROI where OBJECTID is 12.

[image]

Comment: How can the pixel count have many decimals?

Comment: Do the values sum up well?

Comment: These are areas, not cell counts. Divide by cell size to get them.

Comment: You are right @FelixIP. Thank you. I edited my answer to reflect this feedback.